# How to configure client_max_body_size per a location using nginx controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ingress

I would need to configure `client_max_body_size` for a specific location in my `Ingress` configuration file then is the default value. How it is possible to do it? I was looking into the doc but have not found anything. Not don't want do do it globally.

Also if I would use an annotation it would be used for all paths, I just want it for a specific one.

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "4m"
```

```
location /upload-path {
  client_max_body_size 6M;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per [Nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size), you can set `client_max_body_size` in 3 sections:

- http,
- server,
- location

Do set this value, you must change it in `nginx ingress controller` pod, exactly in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Below example:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti <ingres-controller-pod> /bin/bash

$ kubectl exec -ti nginx-ingress-controller-6b85b64f49-rwxlf /bin/bash
```

Edit nginx.conf file.

```
$ vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

In my example hostname from ingress is `my.pod.svc`.

Now you need to find proper `server` part of file. You can search it, as it will be commented like below.

```
## start server <your host name from ingress>
```

Like below:

```
 ## start server my.pod.svc                    
        server {                                                   
                server_name my.pod.svc ;   
...
```

Now you must find proper location. In this example case it will be `/pod`.

```
 location ~* "^/pod" {                                                                                                          

                        set $namespace      "default";
```

Here you must specify this value.

As default it is 2M. During change, don't forget about `;`.

There is similar thread on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069155/maximum-recommended-client-max-body-size-value-on-nginx). In that thread you can also find link with another example [here](https://www.tomaz.me/2013/09/15/avoiding-ddos-attacks-caused-by-large-http-request-bodies-by-enforcing-a-hard-limit-in-your-web-server.html).

After this change you will need to reload nginx.

**EDIT:**

Another option (which was used by OP in this situation) is to use `annotation`.

[client_body_max_size](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#custom-max-body-size)

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m`

This way it would apply whole cluster.

another annotation that can be use is [configuration_snippet annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet). For this example, set size only to `/upload-path`, it would looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   name: nginx-snippet
   annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |

      location /upload-path {

           client_max_body_size 8M;  
      }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I've decided to do in on an ingress rule level - on in the controller.

Comment: So have you used annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` or `configuration-snippet` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212766/11148139 ?

Comment: I have used the annotation and created a new ingress rule specifically for the path needed.

Comment: @PjoterS the solution with the configuration-snippet yielded a 503 for the configured location for me. Do you know why that might be?